# D3.js conditional appending dependeing on type of the object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello everyone
I have collections of items from which i want to display tree view using d3 library. I want to append to rectangle placeholder anything that depends on current processed object type. For now lets assume that I have only two types. I tried to play with it and i finished with below code that is obviously not working. I am able to get the type for individual object, but what next?

Many thanks for help.

Here is the code with comments:

```
let node = svgTree.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes, (d) => {return d.id});

let nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform",(d) => { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";  })
            .style("opacity", 0)


nodeEnter
        .append("rect")
        .attr("y", -fiberHeight / 2)
        .attr("height", fiberHeight)
        .attr("width", fiberWidth)
        .attr("class", "tree-item-placeholder")
        .attr("rx", function() { return  fiberHeight/6; })
        .style("fill", d3.color("Transparent"))
        .on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseOut)
        .on("click", click)
        .select(d=>{
            let type = d.data.feature.Type;
            //now i want to draw different things according to what type is it
            //e.g.
            switch(type){
                case "type1":{
                    this.append("ellipse")
                    .attr("cx", 30)
                    .attr("cy", 0)
                    .attr("rx", 4)
                    .attr("ry", 2)
                }
                case "type2":{
                    this.append("rect")
                    .attr("y", 30)
                    .attr("height", 15)
                    .attr("width", 15)
                }
            }

         }
)
```